# How to set a list (not a string) on a configparser parameter

Tags: python, string, list, configparser

I want to set a parameter of an `.ini` file. I use the `configparser` module, but I notice that every time I save a parameter, it is stored as a string. It there a possibility to convert a string formatted as a list, like `"['p1', 'p2', 'p3']"`, into a list?

This is what I do:

```
list1 = ['ALL'] # initial list value

tmpList = cfg.get('DEFAULT', 'list1')
for i in range(0, len(tmpList)):
    list1.insert(tk.END, tmpList[i])
```

He returns, with a print:

```
[
'
A
L
L
'
]
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? It's not possible to reproduce your problem right away. How do you print your output?

Comment: With the print command directly into the shell. But I solved thanks to @beer44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert python valid string object to actaul by using of `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
l1 = "['p1', 'p2', 'p3']"
l2 = ast.literal_eval(l1)
>>> l2
>>> ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
>>> type(l2)
>>> <class 'list'>
```